# I want to push notifications to UI platform by websockets from .net service which consumes from kafka

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, push-notification

I want to push notifications to UI platform by websockets from .net service which consumes from kafka. do I need to create separate consumer groups for each user ? because I don't have stickiness for user to a service instance.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka has nothing to do with websockets, so your answer depends on how you want to track the offsets.

If each consumer starts a unique consumer group, or otherwise doesn't commit, then you may duplicate websocket send requests across multiple instances of your app (for example, if it has high availability)

Otherwise, with the same consumer group, you're limited to only having as many instances as topic partitions, so you'll want to consider how your data will be structured, keeping in mind that Kafka records are partitioned (and thereby sequentially ordered within the partitions) by key. In other words, you'll want to ensure two notification records for one end user aren't spread across multiple partitions, if they must be delivered in a certain order.